# Age-correcting survey sub-samples

Tags: r, sampling, survey, resampling, survey-sampling

I have a survey of `N = 338` responses. If I analize the `Age` column, I can see that it is more or less normally distributed (mean = 48.2; sd = 14.4).

The histogram + normal curve overlay:
[image]

The Q-Q plot:
[image]

The density plot + normal curve overlay:
[image]

So far, so good.

But when I use a `Boolean` field `Diabetic`, and look at the subsamples for the ones that have, and the ones that do not have diabetes, I get really weird results. The root of the problem is that only `N = 18` subjects in the sample have diabetes (~5%).

If I look at the `Age` distribution for `Diabetic == 1` I get something like this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

One could argue whether this sub-sample stil follows a normal distribution (mean = 58.9, sd = 11.0), but this is not really the major point. The major point is the shift of the `Age` in the sub-sample, which is 10.7 years.

And since the `Age` is a major factor to what I am investigating, all conclusions on the current sub-samples are biased.

**Question**:

Since the `Diabetic == 1` sub-sample is small, I am guessing the best approach would be to down-sample the `Diabetic == 0` sub-sample so that the demographics of both sub-samples would be a match.

Any pointers on how to do something like this? I am using `R` for analysis - are there any simple commands to achieve something like this?

**Clarifications**:

I will be testing whether diabetes is in correlation with the prevalence of Urinary Incontinence (`UI`). But since `UI` is heavily correlated with age, I would like to `Age`-correct both `Diabetic` sub-samples (one group that has diabetes and another group that does not).

The `UI` is also a `Boolean` field, so I will be using a simple "test for equality of proportions". Currently, my data shows that diabetes is in strong correlation for `UI`, but since the diabetic group is ~10 years older than the non-diabetic group, I am afraid that this correlation is only due to the `Age`-shift.

Comment: What is your goal? To find the best prediction? To test whether the distributions are different?

Comment: @keiv.fly: Thank you for your comment. I have edited my question with additional clarifications at the bottom.

Comment: hi, the cdc age-adjusts survey data like this  https://github.com/ajdamico/asdfree/blob/29bbf9690bb82f2eef74331e61112dfeeb2b7128/National%20Health%20and%20Nutrition%20Examination%20Survey/2009-2010%20interview%20plus%20laboratory%20-%20download%20and%20analyze.R#L418